# Kotlin Secondary class constrcutor

Tags: kotlin, constructor

I have a bit of code that is causing an error. i can't seem to find the issue as I have been following a book. the code is below:

```
class Player (_name: String,
               var healthPoints: Int,
               val isBlessed: Boolean,
               private val isImmortal: Boolean) {

    var name = _name
        get() = field.capitalize()
        private set(value) {
            field = value.trim()
        }

    constructor(name: String) : this(name,
                healthPoints = 100,
                isBlesed = true,
                isImmortal = false)
```

I don't understand the error that **this** keyword is creating which is below:

```
Error:(14, 33) Kotlin: None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:   
public constructor Player(name: String) defined in com.bignerdranch.nyethack.Player    
public constructor Player(_name: String, healthPoints: Int, isBlessed: Boolean, isImmortal: Boolean) defined in com.bignerdranch.nyethack.Player
```

Comment: You're using keyword arguments for the last three arguments. Try without them.

Comment: tbh, I have no idea why this causes problems in Kotlin...

Comment: Apparently, [you can't use named arguments with non-Kotlin functions](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/what-is-the-reason-for-not-allowing-named-arguments-for-java-interop/4571) but that seems to imply that the primary constructor is a "non-Kotlin function"...

Comment: Nevermind, I'm being stupid.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in the word `isBlesed`.

Comment: That was the problem thank you! It was weird I didn't see it since the error line was under the word "this" not isBlessed